# Trying to make a modal popup menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a modal popup (e.g. for a yes/no confirmation)such that code doesn't continue to execute until the popup is answered. I know that the recommended method is to add callbacks to each button (menu item), but this method gives  a problem when the menu is part of a loop and one of the results may be a 'break' from the loop, rather than function call.
Anyway, I came up with the code here, using a jquery 1.3 popup widget:

```
var $popUp;
var popupResult;
function wait()
{
    if (popupResult == null) {
        setTimeout(wait, 100);
    }
    else
        return;
}

function CreatePopupMenu(title)
{
    popupResult = null;
    // for safety, timeout the popup if it isn't answered
    setTimeout(function(){ popupResult = false;  }, 3000);
    $popUp = $("<div/>").popup({
        dismissible: false,
        theme: "c",
        afteropen: function () {
            while (popupResult == null)
                wait();
        }
    }).on("popupafterclose", function ()
    {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $("<h4/>", {  text: title }).appendTo($popUp);
}
```

The problem is, the popup doesn't actually appear, the code runs straight into the 'afteropen' callback. If the popup doesn't appear the user cannot use a button to set 'popupResult' so the wait continues forever. If I remove the 'afteropen' callback, the popup appears as expected, but now 'popupResult' remains null (it will be set by callbacks on the buttons which are appended to the menu before it is opened).
A subsidiary question is, why doesn't my 'get-out clause' with the longer timeout ever fire?

Comment: What popup library/widget are you using?

Comment: note that using double equals operator in javaScript `!popupResult == false == null == undefined == 0 == '' == NaN`. simply use not operator and for special checks the triple equals, there for example is `null !== false`.

Comment: I'm using jquery mobile 1.3.1. Good point about the == operators, but this is one simple example - I will be changing it back so that popupresult can be 0,1,2,etc depending on which button was pressed

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned, you can probably find a pre-made solution to your problem; there are tons of jQuery modal popups and boxes out there (Google is your friend.) That said, I can see at least one problem:

```
$popUp = $("<div/>").popup({
  dismissible: false,
  theme: "c",
  afteropen: function () {
    /* while (popupResult == null) */ // <-- REMOVE THIS LINE
    wait();
  }
})
```

That `while` loop is unnecessary. In fact you'll very rarely want to use a `while` loop in this context; you're essentially starting an infinite loop (since it will block execution of other code, browser rendering, etc.). Try removing it, and your code should work more as expected. (I haven't tested this.)

---

A better way to do this would be to structure your popups in HTML like so: (you could create this code in jQuery too, similar to your example)

```
<div class='popup' id='myPopup'>
  <h2>Popup Title</h2>
  <a href='#' class='action' data-action='close'>Close</a>
  <a href='#' class='action' data-action='other'>Press Me!</a>
</div>
```

Then you would simply attach event handlers (i.e., callbacks) to the links/buttons.

```
$('.popup a.action').on('click', function(event) {
   var action = $(this).data('action');
   // Do something... (Close popup, etc.)
});
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, there are many modal popups available but they all require callbacks for each selected item, and they all allow processing to continue past the popup before it is answered by the user. We can't for example put a 'break' (out of a loop) as a callback. Also in my case (and often in the general case) there is further processing after the menu popup, and that processing depends on the result of the popup.

Comment: There's no way to pause execution and wait like you're asking; it's just not possible in JavaScript, you **have** to use callbacks as I demonstrated. If you have code that depends on the result of the modal, then put it in a different function and call that function when the user has made the choice.

Comment: OK, thanks, I accept now that what I'm trying is impossible; I will just have to get used to this single-threadedness (Difficult after years of .NET coding!) and restructure much of my code. ...

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
afteropen: function () {
    while (popupResult == null)
        wait();
}
```

to

```
afteropen: wait
```

or

```
afteropen: function () { wait(); }
```

Currently you endless do `wait` and never leave the loop. That also creates unlimited timeouts.

Using the change you are doing once 'wait' - that does re-setTimeout until popupResult is no more not `!`

---

BTW: This line may not do and even interfere your intentions. If this is executed by the browser right between the user chooses the answer and the next 'wait' timeout - this would reset user's changes.

```
setTimeout(function(){ popupResult = false;  }, 3000);
```

Better save the waitTimeout in `wait`

```
var waitTimeout;

function wait() {
    if (!popupResult) {
        waitTimeout = setTimeout(wait, 100);
    }
}
```

So you can do `clearTimeout` and auto-close the popup:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    if (waitTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(waitTimeout);
        waitTimeout = undefined;
    }
    popupResult = undefined;
    $popUp.close();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Removing 'while (popupResult == null)' just makes the popup return with a null result; it doesn't wait for the user to select anything. Good point though about my 'get-out clause' with the 30000 timeout, although I only really put that in as part of trying to solve the original problem.

Comment: i don't get it right now where you set the "return value of the dialog" (i'm not for real familiar with jquery mobile ;)) however `while (popupResult == null)` doesn't set or return anything but loops endless, blocking any further execution - javaScript is single threaded - so the setTimeout creates timeouts, but these never happen until you leave the while.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use JQuery UI? It ships with it's own Modal Dialog.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

Comment: See my comment on @hamstu 's answer above, the jquery Ui dialog also relies on callbacks for button presses and they all continue processing beyond the point where the popup is called - they don't wait for an answer so not truly modal (in my sense of the word anyway)